# Visited effect tabs CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
.Tab1 {
  background-image: url("http://dl.dg-site.com/wp-content/themes/aeron/images/dl-products-icons5.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-clip: content-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}
.Tab1:hover {
  border: 2px solid #8CC63F;
}
.Tab1:visited {
  border: 2px solid #8CC63F;
}
.Tab2 {
  background-image: url("http://dl.dg-site.com/wp-content/themes/aeron/images/dl-products-icons3.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-clip: content-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}
.Tab2:hover {
  border: 2px solid #8CC63F;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="Tab1"></li>
  <li class="Tab2"></li>
</ul>
```

I have this list and I want that when the user selects an item, the item have border `2px solid #8CC63F.`

My Attempts see in the code, but unfortunately does not work.

Can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need javascript to make things happen when selecting something

Comment: with javascript?interesting...can you post a example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is not working because as far as i know  [:visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) is for anchor **(`<a>`)** tags link elements

so to implement it on list element you will just add a class onClick

```js
var listArray = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=Tab]");

function setVisited() {
  this.classList.add("visited")
}

for ( var list = 0; list < listArray.length;  list++) {
  listArray[list].addEventListener("click", setVisited , false)
}
```

```css
ul li{border:2px solid transparent; margin-bottom: 10px}
ul li:hover,ul li.visited{border:2px solid #8CC63F;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="Tab1">Tab1</li>
  <li class="Tab2">Tab2</li>
</ul>
```

Using Jquery you could do this

```js
$("[class^=Tab]").click(function(){$(this).addClass("visited")})
```

```css
ul li{border:2px solid transparent; margin-bottom: 10px}
ul li:hover{border:2px solid #8CC63F;}
ul li.visited{border:2px solid #8CC63F;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="Tab1">Tab1</li>
  <li class="Tab2">Tab2</li>
</ul>
```